# Failed to find style 'scrollviewstyle' in current theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-scrollview

I am creating a layout in which ScrollView is root element but i am getting this error in layout design tab

> failed to find style 'scrollviewstyle' in current theme

This is xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.myapp.MainActivity">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not too sure what exactly is your issue given the lack of context, one approach that have worked well for me is either:

- Refresh your layout
- Select a theme from the theme dropdown menu (refer to screenshot below)
  [image]

This is because Android Studio (for some reason) could not find the theme you are using for your activity.

Hope this helps